# SSMS SELECT MAX() not returning the max value

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

When I execute this query:

```
insertNewEmail = "INSERT INTO email_accounts (user_no, user_name, email_address, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
newEmailTuple = (int(12), int(12), str('12@email.com'), str('stacks212'))
crsr.execute(insertNewEmail, newEmailTuple)
cnxn.commit()
cnxn.close()
```

I am using the `pyodbc` library for SQL operations.

I get this result in the table.
These are the columns:
*the row numbers are ordered: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.

```
1           1           1@email.com stacks212
2           2           2@email.com stacks212
12          12          12@email.com stacks212
3           3           3@email.com stacks212
4           4           4@email.com stacks212
5           5           5@email.com stacks212
6           6           6@email.com stacks212
```

when I execute this query:

```
lastEmailUserNo = int(crsr.execute("SELECT MAX(user_no) FROM email_accounts").fetchval())
print(lastEmailUserNo)
```

`lastEmailUserNo` returns `6`.

I am trying to get it to return the value `12`.

Does anyone have a solution and/or an answer why the rows are getting inserted out of order?

thanks.

Comment: I suspect the data type of the column user_no is VARCHAR. So you get alphabetical ordering. Define it as INTEGER.

Comment: What's the datatype of the column? If it's a character string (i.e. `VARCHAR`), and not an number (i.e. `INT`), then that's why.  `'12' < '6'` in lexicographic sorting.

Comment: The data type was `NCHAR`, both of you are correct. I changed it to `INT`. it works fine. thank you